# Posso usar select in relationship no laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Tenho uma model que pega os dados com um with no laravel, para pegar dados correlacionados, há forma destes dados correlacionados vir apenas alguns campos específicos e não todos os dados da tabela?

Tentei Fazer assim:

```
return ModelPai::with(array('nomeFuncaoNaModel1'=>function($query){
     $query->select('Campo1_da_tabela1');
}))->with('nomeFuncaoNaModel2')->findOrFail($id);
```

A função no model está assim.

```
public function nomeFuncaoNaModel1()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model1','id_model1','id');
}
```

Da forma como tá, se comentar a linha do $query, ele retorna os dados que desejo, porem com todos os campos e só desejo o campo 1 da relação, não tenho conseguido realizar esta parte, e tem me gerado grande duvida.

Segundo a documentação em [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects), Deveria ser necessário apenas um select logo apos o $this->hasMany()->select(['campos]); Porem o mesmo não funciona

Poderia usar o Join, mas o Join não separa os campos, ele coloca os campos todos juntos no mesmo objeto,

```
data.campo1Tabela1
data.campo2Tabela1
data.campo3Tabela1
data.campo1Tabela2
```

Se ao menos ele colocasse de forma separada(caso conheça alguma forma seria útil saber.) de forma que ficasse assim.

```
data.campo1Tabela1
data.campo2Tabela1
data.campo3Tabela1
data.Tabela2.campo1Tabela2
```

Comment: Coloca a linha onde: "pega os dados com um with no laravel, para pegar dados correlacionados"

Comment: Adicionei o exemplo e como fiz.

Comment: Vê se isto resulta: https://pastebin.com/sMfEDudd

Comment: Não, O objeto inteiro vem vazio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ja tentou fazer dessa forma?

```
return ModelPai::with(array('nomeFuncaoNaModel1'=>function($query){
 $query->select('Campo1_da_tabela1');
}))->with('nomeFuncaoNaModel2')->findOrFail($id)->get(['campo1' , 'campo2']);
```

Não esquecer que para que o laravel reconheça a relação a chave estrangeira precisa estar entre os campos pegos com o select.